# RecyclerView Adapter returns null, when trying to remove items

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have stumpled upon a problem with my `RecyclerView`. I'm at the moment trying to make it so that my context menu(Which appear on Long CLick) can remove an item in my recycler view, but without luck.
I have debugged my app, and every time i click on the button which should delete the item, my app crashes, and i get the information, that my adapter returns `null`.

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Til LongClickListener
CalculationsAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<Calculation> calculations = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    RecyclerView rvCalculations = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvCalculations);
    RecyclerView.ItemDecoration itemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(MainActivity.this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
    rvCalculations.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);


    //Til CostumItemDecoration
    //RecyclerView.ItemDecoration CostumItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(MainActivity.this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
    //rvCalculations.addItemDecoration(CostumItemDecoration);



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.add_new_calculation:
            /* for at starte newcalculation activiteten, gør det i gråt.
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, newcalculation.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            */

            final AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            final View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_namecalculation, null);
            final EditText mNameEditText = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.editText_calculationName);
            Button mNameButton = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.button_nameCalculation);

            //Viser Alertdialogen
            mBuilder.setView(mView);
            final AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
            dialog.show();

            mNameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                //Her skal der være noget der gør at jeg ikke kan give to af samme navn
                //if (mNameEditText.getText() == .getName) ){
                //}

                if (mNameEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.ErrorMessageNameCalculation,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else{
                    RecyclerView rvCalculations = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvCalculations);
                    //calculations = Calculation.createCalculationsList(50);
                    calculations.add(0, new Calculation("  " + mNameEditText.getText()));
                    CalculationsAdapter adapter = new CalculationsAdapter(calculations);
                    rvCalculations.setAdapter(adapter);
                    rvCalculations.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
                    adapter.notifyItemInserted(0);

                    rvCalculations.scrollToPosition(0);

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.SuccesMessageNameCalculation,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    dialog.dismiss();

                }


                }
            });


    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

//Til LongClickListener
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    //Hvad itemet i LongClicket skal gøre

    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case 1:
            adapter.removeItem(item.getGroupId());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Regningen blev slettet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case 2:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);

    }

}


}
```

LogCat:

```
08-03 23:33:44.443 1481-1481/hndvrkerregner.hndvrkerregner E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: package, PID: 1481
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void package.CalculationsAdapter.removeItem(int)' on a null object reference
        at package.MainActivity.onContextItemSelected(MainActivity.java:128)
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace from the logcat.

Comment: @Barns Okay two seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared the class variable `CalculationsAdapter adapter;` at the top of your `Activity` class "MainActivity". But in the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method you are overriding this declaration in this line of code:

`CalculationsAdapter adapter = new CalculationsAdapter(calculations);`

This line should be:

`adapter = new CalculationsAdapter(calculations);`

---

Explanation:

By doing this:

`CalculationsAdapter adapter = new CalculationsAdapter(calculations);`

you are turning `adapter` into a local variable--local only to the method `onOptionsItemSelected()` and thus, `adapter` is then `null` inside `onContextItemSelected()`.

In order to keep `adapter` as a valid class variable with this line of code instead: